# Is _logs/skip/ related to hadoop version?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am doing project about MapReduce task failures. According to Hadoop Beginner's Gudie(Garry Tukington), all of the skip data is stored in _logs/skip/ folder. The author used Hadoop 1.0 version. I am working with Hadoop 2.7.4. Although I tested with skip data, neither output folder nor _logs/skip/ are created. Is _logs/skip folder related to Hadoop version? If I want to skip data in hadoop 2.7.4, what should I do?

Comment: I have added a possible answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, it is not related to hadoop at all.
There are many temporary folders create at the time of execution, which are removed after the execution is completed. This includes log folders, temporary output folders and other temporary folders.

You should not get confused by them. The only guarantee is that it will generate an output folder with a `_SUCCESS` file even though there is no output.

I hope it answers your query.